# passing nesting through segue nil on init methods but valid on viewdidload

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, init

I have made a segue passing a string which tells the next view controller which instance to parse the CoreData for. The problem is, I am using some code that calls init methods and the sent string is not initialized when it is called. However, the segue is working when I display the string in the destination view controller's viewDidLoad

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {

        [self initFakeData];
    }
    return self;
}
```

When that initFakeData method is called it sets up a graph and needs the exercise to hold a valid value

```
- (void)initFakeData
{
    NSString *myExercise=exercise; //returns nil
    if (myExercise==nil) 
    {
        myExercise=@"Default";
    }
}
```

Meanwhile...

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    NSString *myExercise=exercise; //returns value
}
```

exercise is a property that is initialized by the previous view controller in a tableview

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showGraph"]) {
        JBLineChartViewController *destViewController =    segue.destinationViewController;
        NSString *myExericse=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[_exercises valueForKey:@"exercise"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSLog(@"%@",myExericse);
        destViewController.exercise = myExericse;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is correct because during `init` the `exercise` in `JBLineChartViewController` was not set. If you need the `exercise` attribute in the `init` method to set certain behaviour that have to be before `viewDidLoad`, my suggestion is to not use `segue` but do a designated `initWithExercise` and push the controller in code. Maybe like this:

```
- (IBAction)chartButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    JBLineChartViewController *vc = [[ShopViewController alloc]initWithExercise:@"EXERCISE_STRING_HERE"];
    [self showViewController:vc sender:self];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The new view controller is allocated and initialized *before* `prepareForSegue` is called. Anything you need to do with CoreData should be done in `viewDidLoad`. Or you can do it later, e.g. in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`.